# Weird slowdown when using CreateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, createprocess

Let me just start with some example code. I have made a minimum test case for this. To reproduce, two pieces are needed:

First executable, a small application that uses `CreateProcess`. Let's call it *Debugger*.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO         si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    // Starts the 'App':
    auto exe = L"C:\\Tests\\x64\\Release\\TestProject.exe";
    std::vector<wchar_t> tmp;
    tmp.resize(1024);
    memcpy(tmp.data(), exe, (1 + wcslen(exe)) * sizeof(wchar_t));

    auto result = CreateProcess(NULL, tmp.data(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, DEBUG_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    DEBUG_EVENT debugEvent = { 0 };
    bool continueDebugging = true;
    while (continueDebugging) 
    {
        if (WaitForDebugEvent(&debugEvent, INFINITE))
        {
            std::cout << "Event " << debugEvent.dwDebugEventCode << std::endl;
            if (debugEvent.dwDebugEventCode == EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT)
            {
                continueDebugging = false;
            }

            // I real life, this is more complicated... For a minimum test, this will do
            auto continueStatus = DBG_CONTINUE;
            ContinueDebugEvent(debugEvent.dwProcessId, debugEvent.dwThreadId, continueStatus);

        }
    }
    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;

    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    return 0;
}
```

Second executable, a small application that does something stupid which consumes time. Let's call this one *App*:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

__declspec(noinline) void CopyVector(uint64_t value, std::vector<uint8_t> data)
{
    // irrelevant.
    data.resize(10);
    *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(data.data()) = value;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
        LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

        // Activity to be timed
        std::vector<uint8_t> tmp;
        tmp.reserve(10'000'000 * 8);

        // The activity (*)
        uint64_t v = argc;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 10'000'000; ++j)
        {
            v = v * 78239742 + 1278321;

            CopyVector(v, tmp);
        }

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
        ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;

        // We now have the elapsed number of ticks, along with the
        // number of ticks-per-second. We use these values
        // to convert to the number of elapsed microseconds.
        // To guard against loss-of-precision, we convert
        // to microseconds *before* dividing by ticks-per-second.

        ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
        ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

        std::cout << "Elapsed: " << ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << " microsecs" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

Notice how the *debugger* application doesn't really do anything. It just sits there, waiting till the *app* is done. I'm using the latest version of VS2019.

There are now four scenario's that I have tested. For each scenario, I've timed the time it takes for a single iteration (of variable `i`). What I would have expected is that running the *App* (1) and running the *Debugger* (4) would be about the same speed (because the *Debugger* isn't really doing anything). However, the reality is very different:

1. Run *App* (Windows explorer / Ctrl-F5). This will take approx 1 second per iteration on my pc.
2. Run *App* in the Visual Studio debugger (F5). Again, approx 1 second per iteration. What I would expect.
3. Run *Debugger* in the Visual Studio debugger (F5). Again, approx 1 second per iteration. Again, what I would expect.
4. Run *Debugger* (simply from Windows Explorer or ctrl-F5). This time, we have to wait approx. 4 seconds (!) per iteration. Not what I would expect!

I've narrowed down the issue to the `vector<uint8_t> data` argument, which is passed by value (calling the copy c'tor).

I would very much like to know what is going on here... Why is running *debugger* 4 times slower, while it's not doing anything?

-- update --

I have added some stack tracing and profiling capabilities to my little debugger program using a proprietary library... to compare cases (3) and (4) with each other. I've basically counted how often a pointer in my stack trace occurs.

These methods can be found prominently in the results of case (4), but are insignificant in case (3). The number at the start is a simple counter:

```
352       - inside memset (address: 0x7ffa727349d5)
284       - inside RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey (address: 0x7ffa727848b2)
283       - inside RtlAllocateHeap (address: 0x7ffa726bbaba)
261       - inside memset (address: 0x7ffa727356af)
180       - inside RtlFreeHeap (address: 0x7ffa726bfc10)
167       - inside RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey (address: 0x7ffa72785408)
161       - inside RtlGetCurrentServiceSessionId (address: 0x7ffa726c080f)
```

Especially RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey seems to turn up a lot. Unfortunately I have no clue what this means, and Google doesn't seem to be helping...

Comment: What does "without anything attached" mean? What does "n seconds per line" mean? "TestProject.exe" is the "App"?

Comment: @WernerHenze 'Without anything attached' means just starting the EXE from Windows Explorer. "N seconds per line" means that it will take N seconds to produce a single iteration of `i`. And yes, "TestProject.exe" is the app. I'll update the question, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Does the "Debugger" see any debug events in any case? Which and how many? Does that make the difference?

Comment: @WernerHenze Good question, that was also my initial guess. The answer is: not during the execution of the tests, only before and after (loading dll's, start/exit process, etc). In other words: no relevant events are generated. Zero.

Comment: One thing I did notice is that the vector copy constructor makes all the difference in the world. Without it, the timings are pretty much what you would expect. With it, something weird is going on...

Comment: I once read that if you start a process in the MSVC debugger allocations are handled differently. I don't know the reasons, but maybe that is worth looking at. To be honest I am not sure if this helps much because I would expect the allocation to do more if running under a debugger, but your observation suggest the opposite.

Comment: @WernerHenze The benchmarks suggest the exact opposite: that running CreateProcess does something weird, which VS somehow seems to be able to work around.

Comment: std implementation is complex with Visual Studio. Just to give an idea: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp17-20-features-and-fixes-in-vs-2019/ cites a "memcpy fast path", it probably takes a specific path when you debug. I can't reproduce with similar code w/o std. Have you tried to look inside std impl (I won't :-) ?

Comment: please print value of `ULONG NtGlobalFlag;` from [`PEB`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb/index.htm) in case when program run fast under vs debugger and slow in (4) case

Comment: Use WPR. Execute wpr  -start GeneralProfile -start CPU -start VirtualAlloc -start DiskIO and execute then your application which is slow. Then run wpr -stop c:\temp\slowHeapIssue.etl and drop the ETL along with your pdbs for your application somewhere. WPR is part of Windows 10 so it should just work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

different in debug heap. read [The Windows Heap Is Slow When Launched from the Debugger](https://preshing.com/20110717/the-windows-heap-is-slow-when-launched-from-the-debugger/)

and [Accelerating Debug Runs, Part 1: _NO_DEBUG_HEAP](https://ofekshilon.com/2014/09/20/accelerating-debug-runs-part-1-_no_debug_heap-2/)

when process initialized system (ntdll) check are debugger present, if check are environment variable `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` exists and is set to non zero. if no - set the *NtGlobalFlag* (in the PEB) to debug heap use (`FLG_HEAP_ENABLE_TAIL_CHECK`, `FLG_HEAP_ENABLE_FREE_CHECK`, `FLG_HEAP_VALIDATE_PARAMETERS`) all this checks and filling all allocated blocks with special pattern (`baadf00d` and `abababab` at the end of block) make all heap alloc/free slow (compare without this case)

from another side your program most time use for allocate/free memory from heap.

the profile also show this - `RtlAllocateHeap`, `memset` - sure when allocated block filled with magic pattern, `RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey` - this "function" composed from single instruction - `jmp ZwDeleteKey` - so you really not inside this function but "near" it, inside another function related to heap.

---

as noted *Simon Mourier* - why the case (2) and (3) run fast as (1) (when no debugger) but only case (4) more slow ?

from [C++ Debugging Improvements in Visual Studio "14"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-debugging-improvements-in-visual-studio-14/)

> So to improve performance when launching C++ applications with the
>   Visual Studio debugger, in Visual Studio 2015 we disable the operating
>   system’s debug heap.

this is done by set **`_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1`** in debugged process environment . so compare [Accelerating Debug Runs, Part 1: _NO_DEBUG_HEAP](https://ofekshilon.com/2014/09/20/accelerating-debug-runs-part-1-_no_debug_heap-2/) (article is old) - now this is by default.

we can check this by next code in app:

```
WCHAR _no_debug_heap[32];
if (GetEnvironmentVariable(L"_NO_DEBUG_HEAP", _no_debug_heap, _countof(_no_debug_heap)))
{
    DbgPrint("_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=%S\n", _no_debug_heap);
}
else
{
    DbgPrint("error=%u\n", GetLastError());
}
```

so when we start app under debugger - no debug heap because VS debugger add `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1`. when you start your debugger under debugger and app from your debugger - from [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) function

> ***lpEnvironment***
>
> A pointer to the environment block for the new process. If this
>   parameter is NULL, the new process uses the environment of the calling
>   process.

because you pass 0 here - so app use the same environment as debugger - inherit `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1`

but in case (4) - you not set `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` by self. as result debug heap used and run more slow.

Comment: Everyone knows a run is slower under a debugger for various reasons, but - or maybe I missed something - that doesn't explain why 4 (not run under VS debugger) is *slower* than 3 (run under VS debugger).

Comment: @SimonMourier - agree with your question. this only unclear for me. may be this - https://thetweaker.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/091914_1923_acceleratin1.png?w=505&zoom=2 set in project (app and debugger) and this explain why when run code from VS debugger not slow compare without debugger, but this is very unusual and not by default. need more info and research here, but i sure that source of time different - debug heap in 4 case. i be ask print [`NtGlobalFlags`](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntpebteb_8h_source.html#l00071) at begin in all 3 case

Comment: So, yes, setting _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 on Debugger causes 4 to run like the others, so it means debug heap is on for this case? That's weird.

Comment: @SimonMourier - you correct that under debugger, when debug heap is used application must run slow compare without debugger. but why in this case (2)(Run App in the Visual Studio debugger) app not run more slow compare (1), despite it intensive use heap alloc/free all time ? your own assumption *std implementation..* also not explain why under vs debugger code run fast like no debugger, but slow with another debugger (of course we can detect not only debugger present but which concrete, but i sure only special anti-debug protections do this)

Comment: @SimonMourier i can not myself do test/checks here. but i sure that different in heap settings is source of different. so need check for [`NtGlobalFlag`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb/index.htm) at begin. then, if my assumption correct, check for `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` in app - are this variable exist and if yes - it value

Comment: @SimonMourier - by default - no `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` variable in program environment. as result we use debug heap if debugger present and not use it if not present. if `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` exist and not 0 value - debug heap not used even if debugger present. that (2) and (3) run like (1) say that possible VS in OP projects sets `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1`.. but this is only assumption (not sure in this)

Comment: I also tried the "Enable Windows debug heap allocator (Native only)" Tools/Options/Debugging setting. When checked, 3 and 4 run the same. So overall, it looks like it means running under VS debugger sets _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 unless this setting is checked. I think this is what they say here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-debugging-improvements-in-visual-studio-14/ " `... when launching C++ apps with the VS debugger ... we disable the operating system’s debug heap ...`, while just calling CreateProcess w DEBUG_PROCESS enables it.

Comment: @SimonMourier - i just start code under vs2019 debugger and view `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` variable is set. this is all explain. even if we not manually set it in project settings - this is now set by default. because this 2 and 1 run at same time. environment is inherited if not set it direct. as result 3 also run as 1 (app inherit _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 from debugger). but in case 4 - no `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1`

Comment: @RbMm Oh boy... Allright, I've just did all the tests. If you (1) set _NO_DEBUG_HEAP, it works as expected. Question is of course still how does test #3 differ from test #4. Apparently you need to reset both NtGlobalFlag and BeingDebugged, and you have to do it immediately after the `CreateProcess`. After that, the behavior is the same, so apparently they are both checked... With that, I consider your answer the correct one, and I'm happy to award you the bounty. Am I happy with how my code looks... well let's save that discussion for another day...

Comment: @atlaste - *Question is of course still how does test #3 differ from test #4.* - in 3 you start debugger from VS debugger. and VS debugger set `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` in your *Debugger*, then when you start *App* from your debugger - the `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` is **inherited** as all your environment. when you start your debugger separate - nobody set `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` for it. and you not set it when start app too - as result no `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` in case #4 in *App* environment. and you not need reset NtGlobalFlag or BeingDebugged.

Comment: Yeah I understand. From what I can see in my tests, the first thing that happens when you start a process is that the PEB/NtGlobalFlag and the BeingDebugged flag are checked - and if one of that is non-0, it checks if `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP == 1`. I also understand *why* now - if you change the PEB flags, it has side-effects with events (notifications will be missing) for the debugger. That pretty much sums it all up... I just don't like it, because it kinda makes you wonder what other stuff is going to happen when you use CreateProcess.

Comment: @atlaste - but `CreateProcessW` (with `CreateProcessAsUserW` and if very want `CreateProcessInternalW`) only way create new process and not understand *wonder what other stuff is going to happen when you use CreateProcess*. the `BeingDebugged` and `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP != 0` checked at very early stage of process initialization